# DSolve answers with DSolve

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations

I'm trying this code

```
g2[x_] = 1/(2 a (a^2 - b^2)) (-a b^2 ϕ1[x] - b^2 ϕ2[x] + a ϕ3[x] + ϕ4[x]) + c2[x];
g4[x_] = 1/(2 a (a^2 - b^2)) (-a^2 b ϕ1[x] - a^2 ϕ2[x] + b ϕ3[x] + ϕ4[x]) + c4[x];

DSolve[{h1[t] + g2[a t] + h3[t] + g4[b t] == μ1[t], 
h1'[t] + g2'[a t] + h3'[t] + g4'[b t] == μ2[t]}, {h1[t], h3[t]},t]
```

But Mathematica's response is DSolve duplicate

> DSolve[{c2[a t] + c4[b t] + h1[t] + 
>   h3[t] + (-a b^2 [Phi]1[a t] - b^2 [Phi]2[a t] + 
>   a [Phi]3[a t] + [Phi]4[a t])/(
>   2 a (a^2 - b^2)) + (-a^2 b [Phi]1[b t] - a^2 [Phi]2[b t] + 
>   b [Phi]3[b t] + [Phi]4[b t])/(2 a (a^2 - b^2)) == [Mu]1[t], 
>   Derivative[1][c2][a t] + Derivative[1][c4][b t] + 
>   Derivative[1][h1][t] + 
>   Derivative[1][h3][t] + (-a b^2 Derivative[1][[Phi]1][a t] - 
>   b^2 Derivative[1][[Phi]2][a t] + a Derivative[1][[Phi]3][a t] +
>   Derivative[1][[Phi]4][a t])/(
>   2 a (a^2 - b^2)) + (-a^2 b Derivative[1][[Phi]1][b t] - 
>   a^2 Derivative[1][[Phi]2][b t] + b Derivative[1][[Phi]3][b t] +
>   Derivative[1][[Phi]4][b t])/(2 a (a^2 - b^2)) == [Mu]2[
>   t]}, {h1[t], h3[t]}, t]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By combining your responses to people's questions when you posted this yesterday and again today on mathematica.stackexchange.com, by inspection the solution to your system is

```
{h1[t] + g2[a t] + h3[t] + g4[b t] == μ1[t], μ2[t] == μ1'[t]}
```

because your second equation inside DSolve is simply the derivative of your first, as long as μ2[t] == μ1'[t]. That uses all the available information to "solve" your system and without more information I don't believe anything more can be done. At the moment I don't see a way to coax DSolve into seeing this is the solution.

Comment: No, μ2[t] and μ1[t] are absolutely different functions that do not depend on each other. They come from my boundary conditions.

Comment: Take the derivative of each side of your first DSolve equation. The right hand side gives you μ1'[t]. The left hand side gives you the left hand side of your second equation. Thus μ1'[t]==D[lhs1]==lhs2==μ2[t]. But you say that μ2[t] and μ1[t] are absolutely different functions that do not depend on each other. Have I made some error? Or does this say that there can be no solution to your system?

Comment: Ah, I get your point now. So do I need something more? Why doesn't Mathematica respond with any error or else, but only copying my DSolve? μ1 and μ2 are some abstract pre-known functions.

Comment: The second equation is not a simple derivative of the first. If you take `d/dt` of the first equation you will pick up `a,b`'s in front of the two `g` functions.  You can however readily show that the system is overdetermined or has no solutions unless you pick specific forms for your g,u.

Comment: @nenuka: While this often confuses new users, the default response of Mathematica is to simply echo the input when it doesn't understand or cannot find a method to use to handle a problem. Having computers respond with an intelligent response to an unintelligible input needs to be much better. On the issue of whether the second is a simple derivative of the first, we have no idea what your ϕ or c functions will be or how they will handle their arguments or even what your a and b scaling values might be. As agentp wrote, without all the information you have no one can write anything intelligent